# is there any way to deploy custom ML models in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create a flutter app using the ML model from the below link.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/style_transfer/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played with Flutter but there are some promising articles [article 1](https://itnext.io/working-with-tensorflow-lite-in-flutter-f00d733a09c3) [article 2](https://medium.com/@yanweiliu/how-to-use-tensorflow-lite-in-flutter-e323422f64b8) [article 3](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/building-a-cross-platform-image-classifier-with-flutter-and-tensorflow-lite-c7789af9b33a) that gives code snippets to insert tensorflow lite dependencies, to make assets folder and load models. You can check them and I hope you get a first idea how to proceed. Style transfer is a medium to hard coding project though. I suggest to start from simpler tasks as classification problems.

Happy coding

Answer (score 4):

I have used this style_transfer model in flutter app before. unfortunately, I've lost that code (I did not use git). But I can give suggestions on that.

For using this custom model you will have to use https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter.

The trick here is you will have to see model's input shape (image_shape=(384,384,3), style_shape=(256,256,3) and output size (shape=(384,384,3) and also shape of bottleneck). You can resize image using https://pub.dev/packages/image.

with these two, you are good to go. Sorry for bad english and I know I am too much late but maybe someone else will find it useful.

Happy coding!

***Edited:*** So I have found the code. I stored a copy of it in my google drive. I have uploaded it on github https://github.com/Rizwan2613/style-transfer. Please do read Readme file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can upload custom tensorwflow model to firebase ML KIT (custom tab), and integrate with firebase API in your flutter project.

Comment: I already uploaded it, but I don't know what to do after that. 
model loaded in my app successful

Answer (score 1):

There is a recently published flutter plugin for integrating an arbitrary TFLite model.

https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter

Please see the README of the pub package and see how you can bundle the `.tflite` models and how to load / run them in flutter.

There is a blog post on how to use this flutter plugin, but it uses a different model (text classification) as an example.

https://medium.com/@am15hg/text-classification-using-tensorflow-lite-plugin-for-flutter-3b92f6655982